# Delete source file after translation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

is it possible to delete the source file from Autodesk Forge once the translation is complete and still be able to view the translated file in the viewer? If so which endpoints from the APIs should be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two API to delete files on the Forge platform:

1. [DELETE buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-DELETE/): call this API to delete uploaded model raw files such as RVT, NWD, IFC, OBJ, STL and etc. stored on your own Forge OSS bucket (Forge Data Management API). But this might be unnecessary, the upload files should be removed after 24hours or a month regarding the bucket policies, unless these files are uploaded to a bucket with Persistent policy, see here for the bucket [policies](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/retention-policy/).
2. [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/): call this API to delete all derivative bubbles(i.e. the translated files) generated via [POST job](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) of the Forge Model Derivative API.

Comment: is it possible to change the persistence policy for a bucket once it has been created and populated?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't support to modify the bucket policy currently once it has been created. You have to create a new one instead.